# Sass variable declaration precedence

Tags: css, ruby, sass, gruntjs, compass

I am declaring variable of same name in two files. I import them in a following order and found a conflict.

#### Modal.scss

```scss
$gray : #e1e1e1;    // Imported first
```

#### Variable.scss

```scss
$gray : #999;       // imported later
```

The expected behaviour is that the value of `$gray` be overwritten. However, I am getting the firstly imported value (`#e1e1e1`) instead of (`#999`) in CSS.

Am I doing the wrong thing declaring variable multiple times?

Comment: Did you try reversing the order?

Comment: try `$gray : #999 !important;`

Comment: I would suggest you to use some color naming service, [like this one](http://chir.ag/projects/name-that-color/#6195ED) to avoid using the same name for multiple variables.

Comment: @LukaszMuzyka yes, It is taking first value given at first declaration.

Comment: @Fergoso I am not asking the solution. It is about how sass treats variables

Comment: hey @Vucko, yes I can use the different name but i am worried about  sass's variable declaration...

Answer (score 11):

Apparently, Sass will take first variable declaration.

For example when you use Bootstrap in Sass, you have to declare all variables you want to override **before** you import Bootstrap.

```scss
// This will override the default $brand-primary in Bootstrap
$brand-primary: #000;

// Importing Bootstrap
@import 'bootstrap';
```

Comment: Keep in mind that bootstrap uses `!default` keyword when declaring variables. So, your answer might not be true

Comment: Not sure why this answer has the highest score.  It's simply wrong.

Answer (score 6):

### Quick notes on SCSS variables

When processed Sass will output the **current variable value**

```
$color: red;
.class-1 { color: $color; }  // red

$color: blue;
.class-2 { color: $color; }  // blue
```

You can use the **!default** flag to define default variables.

```
$color: red; 
$color: blue !default;       // only used if not defined earlier
.class-1 { color: $color; }  // red
```

Inside function, mixins and selectors variables are **local**.

```
$color: red; // global  

@mixin color { 
    $color: blue; // local
    color: $color
}

.class-1 { color: $color;  } // red  (global)
.class-2 { @include color; } // blue (local)


.class-3 { 
    $color: green;  // local
    color: $color;  // green (local)
}
.class-4 { 
    color: $color;  // red (global)
}
```

You can use the **!global** flag to globalize variables.

```
$color: red; // global  
@mixin color { 
    $color: blue !global; // global
    color: $color
}

//  as we are including color after printing class-1 the color is still red
.class-1 { color: $color;  } // red   
.class-2 { @include color; } // blue

//  at this point the include in class-2 changed the color variable to blue  
.class-3 { color: $color;  } // blue
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you should modified color name like `light-gray: #e1e1e1;` and `dark-gray: #999;`. this will help for solve your problem.

Comment: I know this can be done but question is something else. I do not want solution. I am interested in knowing as how sass treats variables.

Comment: Hey, this link under variable handling section helps in understanding variable declaration. It says Sass takes variable precedence of local scope over global. Thanks Darshak

Answer (score -2):

You should keep your variable names unique to reduce conflicts.

try:

```
$gray : #999 !important;
```

Comment: Using !important should be always absolutely LAST, not first resort.

Comment: @Fergoso I am not asking the solution. It is about how sass treats variables